# how to convert date in jquery or mysql

Tags: jquery, mysql

I have got answers for many different formats , but specifically from this format to the later one. Cant find it.

```
 "February 29, 2016" format to "2016-01-27"
```

Can anyone help as i am a newbee
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('May 1, 2013','%M %d, %Y');
        -> '2013-05-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript (or jQuery) this would look something like this:

```
var date = new Date('February 29, 2016');
var newDate = date.toString('yy-MM-dd');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
select DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('February 29, 2016', '%M %d, %Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Calling `DATE_FORMAT()` in that case is useless.